# Transpose two or more columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
PRIO   Art  Name      Value
1      A     Alpha     0
1      A     Alpha     0
1      A     Beta      1
2      A     Alpha     3
2      B     Theta     2
```

How can I transpose the dataframe, that I have all unique names as a column with the corresponding values to it (note that duplicate rows I want to ignore)?
So in this case:

```
PRIO   Art  Alpha      Alpha_value  Beta   Beta_value  Theta Theta_value
1      A    1             0         1       1           NaN    NaN
2      A    1             3         NaN     NaN         NaN    NaN
2      B    NaN           NaN       NaN     NaN          1     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). A few tricky things to keep in mind:

- You need to specify both `'PRIO', 'Art'` as pivot index
- We can also use two aggregation funcs to get it done *in a single call*
- We have to rename the level 0 columns to distinguish them. So you need to swap levels and rename

---

```
out = df.pivot_table(index=['PRIO', 'Art'], columns='Name', values='Value', 
               aggfunc=[lambda x: 1, 'first'])
# get the column names right
d = {'<lambda>':'is_present', 'first':'value'}
out = out.rename(columns=d, level=0)
out.columns = out.swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
print(out.reset_index())

   PRIO Art  Alpha_is_present  Beta_is_present  Theta_is_present  Alpha_value  \
0     1   A               1.0              1.0               NaN          0.0   
1     2   A               1.0              NaN               NaN          3.0   
2     2   B               NaN              NaN               1.0          NaN   

   Beta_value  Theta_value  
0         1.0          NaN  
1         NaN          NaN  
2         NaN          2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby twice, first to pivot Name and suffix with value. Next groupby same imperatives and find unique values. Join the two.In the joining, drop the duplicate columns and rename others as appropriate

```
g=df.groupby([ 'Art','PRIO', 'Name'])['Value'].\
first().unstack().reset_index().add_suffix('_value')

print(g.join(df.groupby(['PRIO', 'Art','Name'])['Value'].\
       nunique().unstack('Name').reset_index()).drop(columns=['PRIO_value','Art'])\
      .rename(columns={'Art_value':'Art'}))



 Name Art  Alpha_value  Beta_value  Theta_value  PRIO  Alpha  Beta  Theta
0      A          0.0         1.0          NaN     1    1.0   1.0    NaN
1      A          3.0         NaN          NaN     2    1.0   NaN    NaN
2      B          NaN         NaN          2.0     2    NaN   NaN    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of `pd.crosstab()` and `groupby()`.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.crosstab([df['PRIO'],df['Art']], df['Name']),df.groupby(['PRIO','Art','Name'])['Value'].sum().unstack().add_suffix('_value')],axis=1).reset_index()

df
|          |   Alpha |   Beta |   Theta |   Alpha_value |   Beta_value |   Theta_value |
|:---------|--------:|-------:|--------:|--------------:|-------------:|--------------:|
| (1, 'A') |       1 |      1 |       0 |             0 |            1 |           nan |
| (2, 'A') |       1 |      0 |       0 |             3 |          nan |           nan |
| (2, 'B') |       0 |      0 |       1 |           nan |          nan |             2 |
```

Comment: just a small comment, in here the missing values of `Name` are saved as 0, wherever i prefered it as `NaN`

Comment: I am aware that it will be zero, as you point out. Thank you.